# What are the best fonts for numeric data entry?

Tags: user-interface, fonts, numeric

I'm creating a GUI application that requires the user to provide lots of numeric data. What is the best font to display the user's data? I assume that a mono-spaced font would be better in this case, as multiple lines will have the same number of characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably go sans serif monospace.

What other fonts are you using for the rest of the application?  If the answer is "Arial", "Arial Monospace" is probably the matching font for the numbers.

Comment: But 0's and 6's look very similar in Arial.

Comment: Here's a monospace Arial variant: http://tinyurl.com/yj49u7v

Not very similar to my eye, although glad to know it's a problem for some.

Answer (score 6):

My favorite is [Consolas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas)

Answer (score 3):

**courier/courier new**   *also looks better.*

Answer (score 0):

anything monospace will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed on monospace but let the USER choose which one and the size - you have to set one by default

Answer (score -1):

I'm a fan of [Lucida Console](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1262) or PT Mono.